# References for learning Thompson's group $V$, $F$ and $T$ and their properties

Tags: reference-request

I want to learn about the structure of Thompson's group $V$, $F$ and $T$ and their properties. I also want to know about the properties of actions of these groups on $\mathbb{S}^1$ and the cantor set $\mathcal{C}$.

I am aware of the following books and references:

1. Office hours with a geometric group theorist, edited by Matt Clay and Dan Margalit
2. Thompson's group F by James Belk available at: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0708.3609.pdf
3. Introductory notes on Richard Thompson's groups by Cannon, Floyd and Parry available at: http://people.math.binghamton.edu/matt/thompson/cfp.pdf

I was wondering if there are any other books and references where I can find information about these groups and various properties associated to their subgroups and actions.

Thanking you in advance!!

Comment: Interesting topic. Will wait for answers. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Might be a bit at an introductory level, but regarding group F specifically, I find the thesis by Daniel Yeow from the University of Melbourne very well organized and pleasant to read, with interesting applications discussed at the end.

Some of the references on his thesis might be of your interest as well.

Here's the link:

http://www.danielyeow.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/honoursthesisfinal.pdf